# Area of curve given its tangent point.

Tags: integration, self-learning, area, tangent-line

> Question : The area bounded by the curve $y = (x+1)^{2}$, its tangent at point $(1,4)$ and $x = -1$.

I began by finding the tangent to curve at points $(1,4)$

Differentiating the curve $w.r.t.x$ I got : $$y' = 2(x+1)$$
and substituting for $x = 1$, I got the slope of the tangent as : $$m = 4$$

Therefore the equation of the tangent of the curve is: $$y=4x$$

The tangent intersects the $x-axis$ at the origin. And the curve $y = (x+1)^{2}$ intercepts the $x-axis$ at point $-1$.

So to find the area between these 2 curves I integrated as follows:
$$\int_{-1}^{0} (x+1)^{2} - 4x \ =\frac{1}{3}x^{3} + x - x^{2} \ ; from \ x = -1  \ to \ x = 0 $$
$$ = \frac{7}{3} $$

Is this the correct method and solution?

**EDIT** As mentioned in the comments, integrating between $(-1,1)$ we get:
$$= \frac{8}{3}$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your approach is correct but the upper bound of the integral is not correct. It should be $1$ and not $0$. The tangent to the curve is drawn at point $(1,4)$ and note the x-coordinate of the point is $1$. So the correct integral should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_{-1}^{\color {blue} 1} \left[(x+1)^{2} - 4x\right] ~ dx = \frac{8}{3}$

[image]

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @DBZrasengan16 you are welcome. I just added a diagram too if that helps further.

Comment: Thank you for this. Could you recommend any books that I can go through to practice these type of question?

Comment: I have not read myself but I have heard from others about _The Humongous Book of Calculus Problems_ but you should also be able to get practice problems from many online sites, such as https://opentextbc.ca/

Comment: Specific link to area of a region between two curves - https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-2/pages/2-1-areas-between-curves

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$$\int\limits_{x=-1}^1 ((x+1)^2 - 4 x)\ dx = \frac{8}{3}$$